# Unable to install the default jdk package on Debian

Tags: java, debian, java-6

I'm a Debian newbie and trying to install JDK on my new OS, receiving the following error:
Please insert the disk labeled:
Debian GNU/Linux 7.8.0 *Wheezy* - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20150110-14:43
in drive /media/cdrom/

I am using the following commands: 
apt-get update + 
apt-get install default-jdk

I searched for the requested file but with no success but with no luck.
I'd be happy to get an explanation to this error and where can I find the requested file.
The OS is installed as a Virtual Box guest.

/etc/apt/sources.list:

```
#

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.8.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20150110-14:43]/ wheezy contrib main

deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.8.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20150110-14:43]/ wheezy contrib main

deb http://debian.co.il/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://debian.co.il/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://debian.co.il/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib
deb-src http://debian.co.il/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib
```

Comment: Most likely you have to remove your cdrom from the /etc/apt/sources.list file. Show us the contents of this file.

Comment: @VGe0rge, I copied the file content to the main message.

Comment: Questions about software installation are off-topic. This site is for programming questions.

Comment: First of all StephenC is right, the most suitable place for this kind of questions is [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/). The answer of k0staa is for installing the oracle jdk (and it will actually not work) , if you want the default jdk (openjdk) you could only remove the line "deb cdrom...." and do the update.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to delete the following line:
   `deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.8.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20150110-14:43]/ wheezy contrib main`
2. Then update apt:
   `$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
3. Now you should be good to install.

Answer (score -1):

Open /etc/apt/sources.list (as a root or super user)
You need to remove second from two first lines(leave just this one mark with '#') :

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.8.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20150110-14:43]/ wheezy contrib main
```

and add this lines to the end of the file:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu wheezy main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu wheezy main
```

After you save the file and exit you need to run this command (adding repo keys):

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
```

And this one:

```
apt-get update
```

Now you are ready to install java, for exemple:

```
apt-get install oracle-java7-installer oracle-java7-set-default
```

Comment: There is no need to add a ppa for the user to install the default jdk. Especially not a non-Debian repository which isn't maintained by the debian-security team

Comment: I dont think that there is a default jdk repository anymore. I think there is only  Open JDK (repo name: default-jdk). But if I'm wrong please just give instructions. I'dont use debian anymore.

Comment: default-jdk is a meta package which depends on the openjdk-6-jdk, but openjdk-7-jdk is also available. https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/default-jdk